# Expose several web service inside one AAR

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I have to develop an application exposing several web services.
It is possible to do it inside one AAR or do I need to expose them inside a WAR ?

Tks a lot
Nicolas

Comment: It is a 'Axis ARchive' allowing the web service deplyment, I know how to use it to deploy one single webservice, but is it possible to deploy several webservice inside only one AAR ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single archive file, and in the service.xml you can define services in a group.
Check this [article](http://wso2.org/library/2060) fro further info